# How do I override any properties of Locale.Java class for date number digit in English for entire application.

Tags: java, localization

I am using hindi locale in java .  **Locale (java.util.Locale)**  governs, which  properties & features. it’s useful for me .
But I need to  number digit  , time , date in English  but currently showing in hindi language .

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of formatting: with default Locale or the custom one. So if you need to format messages, but numbers should be in one specific format, then you need to explicitly specify the locale for numbers, time and date. Here is an example for numbers with [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
String number = nf.format(1000000);
```

Comment: I want to change any properties in  locale class bec if go above logic. There will be huge change in entire application . I have Count of numberformat(500) , decimalformate(200) , simpalDateFormat (300) .

Comment: @kuldeepchauhan calling XXXFormat without a locale means you accept the local settings - if that's not what you want you should specifiy the locale. Also a simple regex find & replace in your IDE would probably make that change reasonably easy, even on 100s of instances.

Comment: @solomkinvm , I don't want go with idea . Please let me know "if u have other idea" .

Comment: thx for u idea  but i got center change Locale.setDefault(Category.FORMAT, new Locale("en", "US"));                 it is working fine .